# ACF - Post object field custrom taxonomy are not displayed

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am a wordpress developer,
this is all about admin end ,I am not talking about front end.

I have created a field of type post object(field name is End slide) by the help of ACF plugin.
The filters are: Filter by Post type:post
         AND Filter by taxonomy:Ending slide(category created by me)

There are 2 posts having the **Ending slide** category, but none of them are showing in the **End slide** field,when I try to create or edit a post.
Any help will be appreciated.
Let me know if you need any other information.
thanks

Pushan

Comment: and it is not a custom post type?

Comment: no its not custom post type.

Comment: add some code so we can he;p you here.

Comment: I haven't written any code for it .Its just ACF post object type field and but that field is not getting populated with post objects.If you want I can give you the admin details.Do you want the admin details?

Comment: You write that you have two posts, in the ending slide category - but that your filter goes by a taxonomy - shouldn't it be set to `post type = post` AND `post category = Ending slide` ?

Comment: or `post taxonomy = Ending slide` - not just `taxonomy = Ending slide` since it can't be both a post AND a taxonomy on the same time

Comment: I understand what you are saying but ACF provides only filter by post type and filter by taxonomy options

Comment: My bad - I thought you were talking about the location rules - you are talking about the filters.. Then I can't see that you should be doing anything wrong?

Comment: please check this link, it shows a screenshot :https://i.stack.imgur.com/u77Ug.png

Comment: please suggest a solution if you want admin credentials I can provide you with that but handle it with care this is our staging.

Comment: please suggest a solution.If you want admin credentials I can provide you with that but handle it with care this is our staging.

Comment: I just noticed something ,post object field belonging to a certain field group is not populating other post object fields are working just fine....What does this imply?